# Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'categories/signIn'

Tags: typescript, angular6

i am creating a project in angular in which i have applied routing in components. when i move  from main component to other components, the routing is working fine , but when i try to go for other components, i am getting this error-

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'categories/signIn'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'categories/signIn'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1384)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
```

i have applied routing through two files, in my app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {FrontendComponent} from './layouts/frontend/frontend.component';
import {CategoriesComponent} from './layouts/categories/categories.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {SignInComponent} from './layouts/sign-in/sign-in.component';

const routes: Routes = [
     {path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent},
     {path: 'signIn', component: SignInComponent},
     { path: '',      component: FrontendComponent }
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

in my app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FrontendModule } from './layouts/frontend/frontend.module';
import { FrontendComponent } from './layouts/frontend/frontend.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './layouts/categories/categories.component';
import { SignInComponent } from './layouts/sign-in/sign-in.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CategoriesComponent,
    SignInComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FrontendModule,
    CategoriesComponent,
    SignInComponent,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
        FrontendComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and in my frontend.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FrontendComponent } from './frontend.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../common/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from '../common/footer/footer.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: FrontendComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    FrontendComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    FilterPipe
  ],
  providers: [FilterPipe],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class FrontendModule { }
```

i Know there can be mistakes in my component specifications. if any one can find the issue, please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

As i see your routes configuration does not have the configuration for the route **`'categories/signIn'`**

If you need nested routing you should have a children under categories,

```
 path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent,
 children: [{ path: 'categories/signin', component: SignInComponent}]
```

if not just use /signIn in the application

Comment: i have updated my app.routing.module file, please check and tell me where is issue

Comment: no, i don't want nested routing, i just want simple routing that can make me to move in different components. for example, if i am moving from home to categories, then i should also be able to move from categories to sign in. In that particular case this is producing error

Comment: then your route should simply as yourapp/signin

Comment: sir can you please specify, where i should make changes

Comment: i am just specifying  as  <a routerlink ="signIn">button</a>. The another routing is done in above files only.

Comment: try this  routerLink=[/signIn']></a>